# Disable selected option from drop down One to drop down Two in angular 2 - Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

```
<div class="row no-overflow">
    <div class="col-md-1 window-pad-height">
        <mat-label> Opportunity 1: </mat-label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
        <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
            <mat-select placeholder="select" [(ngModel)]="oppurtunityOne" [disabled]="selectedRankingCriteria.viewValue!=='Custom'">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let op1 of OppurtunityList" [value]="op1">
                    {{op1.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row no-overflow">
    <div class="col-md-1 window-pad-height">
        <mat-label> Opportunity 2: </mat-label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
        <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
            <mat-select placeholder="select" [(ngModel)]="oppurtinityTwo" [disabled]="selectedRankingCriteria.viewValue!=='Custom'">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let op of OppurtunityList" [value]="op" [disabled]="oppurtunityOne.viewValue">

                    {{op.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row no-overflow">
    <div class="col-md-1 window-pad-height">
        <mat-label> Opportunity 3: </mat-label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
        <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
            <mat-select placeholder="select" [disabled]="selectedRankingCriteria.viewValue!=='Custom'">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let op3 of OppurtunityList" [value]="op3">
                    {{op3.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row no-overflow">
    <div class="col-md-1 window-pad-height">
        <mat-label> Opportunity 4: </mat-label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
        <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
            <mat-select placeholder="select" [disabled]="selectedRankingCriteria.viewValue!=='Custom'">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let op4 of OppurtunityList" [value]="op4">
                    {{op4.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">View</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSON DATA

```
    OppurtunityList: any[] = [
    { value: 'col-1', viewValue: 'datatoDisplay1' },
    { value: 'col-2', viewValue: 'datatoDisplay2' },
    { value: 'col-3', viewValue: 'datatoDisplay3' },
    { value: 'col-4', viewValue: 'datatoDisplay4' },
    { value: 'col-5', viewValue: 'datatoDisplay5' },
    { value: 'col-6', viewValue: 'datatoDisplay6' },
    { value: 'col-7', viewValue: 'datatoDisplay7' },
    { value: 'col-8', viewValue: 'datatoDisplay8' },
    { value: 'col-9', viewValue: 'datatoDisplay9' }
  ];
```

How to disabled selected option from drop down using typescript ?
What logic should I put here, I dont know how to disabled the selected option.
Is it possible to handle using ngModel?

Comment: Means you want to disable option of dropdown 2 which alredy selected by dropdown 1, am i right?

Comment: @R.Viral yes Sir!

Comment: thanks but when i select 4 , then 1 2 3 4 option get disabled here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 2nd drop down you can write like

```
<div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
    <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
        <mat-select placeholder="select" 
                    [(ngModel)]="oppurtinityTwo" 
                    [disabled]="selectedRankingCriteria.viewValue!=='Custom'">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let op of OppurtunityList" 
                        [value]="op" 
                        [disabled]="oppurtunityOne.viewValue === op.viewValue">
                {{op.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: can i do this for drop-down three and four?

Comment: yup you can, check `ng-modal` and `condition` according your disable things.

Comment: [disabled]="oppurtunityOne.viewValue === oppurtunityTwo.viewValue || oppurtunityThree.viewValue === oppurtunityFour.viewValue I was trying to disabled the save button if the four drop down options are same I'm going right?

Comment: above logic output is` value-1` is equal to `value-2` then its disable or`value-3 `equal to `value-4` then its disable. if you want to compare `value-1` with all drop down then try like `[disabled]=" (value-1 === value-2 || value-1 === value-3 || value-1 === value-4)"`

Comment: I did it the same way but button gets enabled after selected third drop down! "(oppurtunityOne.viewValue === oppurtunityTwo.viewValue || oppurtunityTwo.viewValue === oppurtunityThree.viewValue || oppurtunityThree.viewValue === oppurtunityFour.viewValue)"  i tried this way but this one is also not working!

Answer (score 2):

Add a function that takes an input you can evaluate in your component:

```
<!-- html -->
<mat-select placeholder="select" 
[disabled]="disableSelectFunction(selectedRankingCriteria.viewValue)">

//Typescript
disableSelectFunction(value){
    if (value === 'myValue'){
        return true; // disabled
    } else {
        return false; // not disabled
    }
}
```

Comment: if you dont mind could you explain me this in stakblitz?

Comment: You are passing a value to a function, evaluating it and returning a boolean result based on the evaluation of said value. I am not going to write your code for you.